# Passport local - Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, pug, passport.js

I am using [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) in my app. When I render views to display user information, I'm able to display user information (I'm using jade, btw) in that view:

```
#user
  p #{user.fname} #{user.lname)
```

However, that view extends a layout, and in that layout, I am not able to access the user variable. My end goal is to have the nav bar in the layout and display a few user related items. I know I could set variables in my blocks, but I don't want to have to set them in every single view (that seems far more repetitious than it should be, and seems like the wrong way to do things). How can I make my user information available to my layout that my views extend and do it in one place?

**layout.jade**

```
...

#user
  if(user != null)
    ul.nav.navbar-right.navbar-nav
      li.dropdown
        a.dropdown-toggle(href='#', data-toggle='dropdown') #{user.email} <--BREAKS HERE

...
```

**user.jade**

```
extends layout

...

#user
  h1.title Welcome #{user.email} <--WORKS FINE HERE

...
```

Comment: can you post the relevant sections of the layout and the view?  That would help to troubleshoot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**layout.jade**

```
block header

    #user
      if(user != null)
          ul.nav.navbar-right.navbar-nav
              li.dropdown
                  a.dropdown-toggle(href='#', data-toggle='dropdown') #{user.email}

block content
```

or 

**layout.jade**

```
block header
    #user
      if(user != null)
          ul.nav.navbar-right.navbar-nav
              li.dropdown
                  a.dropdown-toggle(href='#', data-toggle='dropdown') 
                      | #{user.email}

block content
```

**user.jade**

```
extends layout

block content
    #user
        h1.title Welcome #{user.email}
```

Comment: The check for `user` isn't the issue. The issue is that `user` is not defined in layout.jade, so `user` will always be null. My question is more about how I can expose `user` globally and just once, so that it will be available to all layouts and views (when a user is logged in, of course).

Comment: if user is available to user.jade (you wrote user.js but I am assuming this is a typo), then it is available to any other jade file extended in it.  Try the other option I added

Comment: Yeah, neither option works. `if(#{user} != null)` actually produces the error `Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: Let's do a little troubleshooting.  Remove all the code from layout.jade and insert the following line and see if the user variable shows up  "h1.title Welcome #{user.email}"

Comment: Nope. I get the error `Cannot read property 'email' of undefined`

Comment: that is strange.  did you see my edit about how to structure extends in jade files?  If your Jade files are properly structured, there should not be any issue having the same variables show up across all of them

Comment: Well, my question specifically mentioned that I'm trying to find a way to avoid this as it will be repetitious. I don't want to pass in user variables in every single view. If I ever change user info, there will be a huge amount of files to go through to change that info. I'm looking for a way to expose user _once_ so that my layout can use it no matter which view is calling it.

Comment: But that's the point exactly. The layout header block outlines the navbar and all other views simply build upon it by calling "extends layout". In order to make this work, you need to define blocks (block header, block content, etc) in the layout so that the other Jade files can define which part of the layout is being overridden .

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding. I understand that the views build upon the layout. My problem is that `user` is not available in my layout.jade. I am getting the error `Cannot read property 'email' of undefined`. I have defined blocks to add in the content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64664/discussion-between-takinola-and-jordan).